# Outlook: save attachments to an FTP Server

Tags: delphi, outlook, ftp

In my application, I consult my emails from Outlook. I save them to hard drive with the attachments. That works well:

```pascal
atcments : OLEVariant;   
...
atcments := itemOL.Attachments.Count;
for counter := 1 to atcments do
begin
  attfilename := Copy (('My file ' + itemOL.Attachments.item(counter).FileName), 0, 120);
  itemOL.Attachments.item(counter).SaveAsFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\ MyFolder \' + attfilename);
end;
```

Now, I want to save the attachments to an FTP Server using the Indy components. After connecting to the FTP Server, I changed the last line to:

```pascal
IdFTP1.Put (itemOL.Attachments.item(counter).FileName, attfilename);
```

But it does not work, the file is not saved in the FTP server.

Is there a solution to save the attachments directly to the FTP server without going through saving on the hard disk and then sending them to the FTP server?

Comment: "*it does not work*" - In what way exactly? Are you getting an error? A blank file? Please be more specific. One problem I see is your original code deals with absolute paths, but your non-working code deals with relative paths instead. "*save the attachments ... without going through ... the hard disk*" - without a disk file, the only other option that `TIdFTP` supports for uploads is a `TStream`, but I see no way to get access to each attachment's raw data to put into a stream, so you will have to use disk files.

Comment: thank you Remy.      when running i get an error message saying that it is impossible to open the file in the path xxxx.      
I will follow your advice: go through the disk files then send them to the FTP server.   The only problem is: if the attached file is large, it will take a long time to save this file on the FTP server. I have no choice so I will use the disk files.

Comment: the error message: "the xx project raised the exception class" EFOpenError "with the message 'Unable to open file:" D: \ My file.pdf "the specified file could not be found'

Comment: well, that should tell you that you are not working with file paths correctly, so I suggest you double check your inputs and logic. The file path you are giving to `IdFTP1.Put()` is wrong.

Comment: yes, The file path you give to `IdFTP1.Put ()` is incorrect. Not possible to get raw data (attached files) from Outlook directly.

Comment: Since you know `SaveAsFile()` works, simply save that working file path in a variable that you can use for both Outlook and FTP, eg: `att := itemOL.Attachments.item(counter); attfilename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'MyFolder\' + att.FileName; att.SaveAsFile(attfilename); IdFTP1.Put(attfilename);`

Comment: Thanks Remy. I just did it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a disk file, the only other option that `TIdFTP` supports for upload is a `TStream`, but I see no way to get access to each attachment's raw data to put into a stream, so you will have to use disk files.

One problem I see with your approach is that your original code deals with absolute paths, but your non-working code deals with relative paths instead.  Since you know `SaveAsFile()` works, simply save that working file path in a variable that you can use for both Outlook and FTP, eg:

```pascal
atcments : Integer;
att : OleVariant;
attfilename : string;
...
atcments := itemOL.Attachments.Count;
for counter := 1 to atcments do
begin
  att := itemOL.Attachments.item(counter);
  attfilename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'MyFolder\My file ' + att.FileName;
  att.SaveAsFile(attfilename);
  IdFTP1.Put(attfilename);
end;
```